# Reliable wipe files after ACTION_VIEW intent finished (Android/Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I receive a PDF file in b64 encoding and put it as file decoded to cacheDir. This may be a PDF file or image etc. This works fine.

### What I want

Upon the file is stored in cacheDir, I run an ACTION_VIEW intent to view it with the system PDF or image viewer. As soon as this is done, I like to wipe the file from cacheDir.

### The problems

1. The fist problem is, that my onActivityResult() function always returns null in *data* instead of the intent. Therefore, I do not know the filename (URI) to delete inside of onActivityResult(). I did not manage to let onActivityResult() return the intent in *data*. Code is below.

Is there something wrong in the code?

2. The second issue is that, if someone simply closes the viewer, the onActivityResult() function is not called anymore and the file stays in the cacheDir folder. I don't like this as it is a security issue if such PDFs or images stay here.

Is there a reliable cleanup functionality?

### Code (Kotlin)

NOTE: The *openFile()* function is called by JavaScript from inside a WebView. It starts the whole process I'm talking about.

```
(...)

class MainView : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WebviewTestTheme {    
                (...)
            }
        }
    }
    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == OPEN_INTENT_RESULT) {
            if (data != null) {
                val result = data.getStringExtra("returnedData")
                println("Success $result")
            } else {
                // Handle the error
                println("Error: Intent did not return any data")
            }
        }
    }
}

(...)

class JavaScriptInterface(private val context: Context) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    @Throws (IOException::class)
    public fun openFile(filename: String, base64binary: String) {
        // store in cache dir
        val storageFilePath = File(
            context.cacheDir.toString() + "/" + filename
        )

        println("Store the file to [$storageFilePath]...")
        val pdfAsBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(base64binary, 0)
        try {
            val os = FileOutputStream(storageFilePath)
            os.write(pdfAsBytes)
            os.flush()
            os.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "FAILED TO STORE THE FILE!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            e.printStackTrace()
            println("ERROR: Failed to save the file")
            return
        }
        println("File saved successfully")

        if (!storageFilePath.exists()) {
            // saved file not found?
            Toast.makeText(
                context, "FAILED TO ACCESS FILE!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            println("ERROR: Failed to access the previously saved file at [$storageFilePath]")
            return
        }

        val apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
            storageFilePath
        )
        var type: String? = "application/octet-stream"
        val extension = File(filename).extension
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
            extension.lowercase()
        )

        // create intent
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(
            apkURI,
            type
        )
        intent.putExtra("returnedData", storageFilePath)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT)

        try {
            startActivityForResult(getActivity(context)!!, intent, OPEN_INTENT_RESULT, null)
            Toast.makeText(context, "File gets opened...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            println("ERROR: No suitable application found to open this file.")
            Toast.makeText(context, "No suitable application found to open this file.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```